# passing array to tweenjs won't work

Tags: javascript, closures, tween.js

I want to animate multiple screen objects with tween.js.

The objects are organized in an array and I want to pass each individual element to the tween function which looks roughly as follows:  http://jsfiddle.net/8L9Dz/

```
var target1 = document.getElementById( 'target1' );
var target2 = document.getElementById( 'target2' );

targets.push(target1);
targets.push(target2);

for(var i = 0; i < 2;i++ ){
    var tween = new TWEEN.Tween( targets[i].dataset )  // i'th element
        .to( { rotation: 360, y: 300 }, 750 )
        .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.InOut )
        .onUpdate( function() {
            updateBox( targets[i], this );
        })
        .start();
}
```

When I run the code locally firefox tells me that "box is undefined" - this corresponds to the 1st line in updateBox(...)

I guess this is somehow related to the closure of the function, but I'm no expert in JavaScript - does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rewriting your code as follows to avoid closure binding of loop variable:

```
var tween = new TWEEN.Tween( targets[i].dataset )  // i'th element
    .to( { rotation: 360, y: 300 }, 750 )
    .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.InOut )
    .onUpdate( (function(id, ctx) { 
        return updateBox(targets[id], ctx); 
    })(i, this) )
    .start();
```

#### UPDATE:

`onUpdate` should receive a function as a parameter, I missed that. Try as follows:

```
...
.onUpdate( (function(id, ctx) { 
        return function() { updateBox(targets[id], ctx) }; 
    })(i, this) )
...
```

#### UPDATE2:

`this` should not be passed to `onUpdate`, so try this:

```
var tween = new TWEEN.Tween( targets[i].dataset )  // i'th element
              .to( { rotation: 360, y: 300 }, 750 )
              .repeat(Infinity)
              .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.InOut )
              .onUpdate( (function(id) { 
                return function () { updateBox(targets[id], this); };
              })(i) )
              .start();
```

Note: In your .zip you didn't use targets[i].dataset in Tween constructor, pay attention

Comment: doesn't do it either - now ff complains about "TypeError: t is undefined" in tween.js. (The second last semicolon needs to be removed)

Comment: So what doesn't work now? I can't make your jsfiddle work, TWEEN is undefined, so I'm only guessing, what can be wrong.

Comment: @MikeDooley Please try new version.